# Standalone(static) curl library in linux with just http, https support

Tags: linux, libcurl, static-linking

I am developing an application in Linux, which requires static library of curl.Only http and https support is required.I have tried many ways like -Wl,-Bstatic -libcurl , linking to libcurl.a etc. Most alarming is that, I haven't seen anybody who has been successful in doing so, in linux.Only thing I found was in Windows,
[Linking project with statically build curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20461682/linking-project-with-statically-build-curl)

But in linux , almost all answers are like following.

[Static linking libcurl using c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7279764/static-linking-libcurl-using-c).

Is it so? Whether it is impossible to make standalone library of curl in linux ?

Following are my build options and results

1. -Wl,-Bstatic -pthread -lcrypto -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lcurl
   No error !!!!!
2. -Wl,-Bstatic -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -lcurl
   errors ... cannot find -lgcc_s
3. -static -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -lcurl 
   lot of errors starting with undefined reference "idn_free" 
   4.-static -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -ldn -lcurl 
   no change.... lot of errors starting with undefined reference "idn_free"
4. -static /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl.a 
   no change.... lot of errors starting with undefined reference "idn_free"

Comment: Following are my build options and  results                                         1.   -Wl,-Bstatic -pthread -lcrypto -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldl -lcurl
No error !!!!!
2. -Wl,-Bstatic -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -lcurl
 errors ...cannot find -lgcc_s
3. -static -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -lcurl
lot of errors starting with undefined reference "idn_free"

Comment: continued.....4. -static -pthread -lcrypto -ldl -ldn  -lcurl
no change....
lot of errors starting with undefined reference "idn_free"
5. -static /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.a /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
no change....
lot of errors starting with undefined reference "idn_free"

Comment: @DanielStenberg I have edited the question by adding my build results.My requirement is to have a completely standalone application in linux.

Comment: `idn_free` comes from libidn (which is replaced by libidn2 in current curl)

Comment: @DanielStenberg From your response , I am assuming that it is possible to have static linking with libcurl.That itself is a big relief. The idn_free is one of the errors. One such error is undefined reference to `X509_get_subject_name. Actually the undefined references are happening in functions such as ossl_send,X509V3_ext, cert_verify_callback, X509_name_oneline, fix_hostname, servercert etc

Comment: You need to keep adding the missing libs to the link line. `X509_*` comes from openssl.

Comment: Adding /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgnutls-openssl.a didn't help.I will try with the latest version of openssl.

Comment: That doesn't look at all correct. it would be libcrypto.a or libssl.a, and it should probably be the same version your curl was built against to be safe

Comment: -static
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypto.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libidn.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libssl.a
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcurl.a,           libcrpto.a was already there.Now I have added libssl.a as well. But the same errors. Am I missing something here ?.

Comment: @BusyTraveller did you ever figure anything out?